# Regex for matching groups without end delimiter

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
@# Text2@#  Line1@#Last line without delimiter
```

So each element is started with `@#` and finished with `@#`, but last element has only start delimiter. and I would like to have three (in this case, but number is not fixed) matched groups:
`Text2`,
`Line1`,
`Last line without delimiter`

I did this regex:

```
(@#(.*))
```

And it's working, but only when each element located on separated line (`.*` is limited with LF char).
Also it's very preferable to do not use modern regex features, because regex engine is boost 1.34 (legacy code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
@#(.*?)(?=@#|$)
```

Details:

- `@#` - delimiter
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (to match any chars, it might suffice to add `(?s)` at the pattern start, or use `[\w\W]` instead of `.` here)
- `(?=@#|$)` - up to the first `@#` or end of string.

Comment: thanks. You are regex monster. Very small correction: @#(.*?)(?=@#|$)

Comment: @SergeyAlikin Ah, if you need the matches without the `@#`, right, capture the non-greedy dot.